# jQuery Validate Issue

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using the jQuery validate plugin to validate a multi-step form like this one:
http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/multipart/

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it to work at all and there is a total lack of documentation to guide me through implementation. I think the accordion part of script is firing correctly because the bottom half of the form is being hidden and a 'next' button has been successfully inserted. However, the form never validates or delivers an error message and it is impossible to move on to the next step.

Check it out here:
http://www.loftist.com/?page_id=78

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Firebug or similar to debug the issues you have. First one is:

```
  if (v.form()) {
```

On line 235 which throws a  `v is undefined` error because v does not exist in that scope.

Comment: Ahh I didn't know that Firebug would return JS errors like that - very useful, I think I got the problem - Thanks!

Comment: Firebug has a full javascript debugger built in - extremely handy!